Austrian coming back to Austria from living in USA
I am an Austrian.  I have lived in USA for 20 years with green card.  I am planning to move back to Austria. How long does it take for me to qualify for public healthcare and any other resident/citizen rights upon returning to Austria?

What has your own research revealed? What exactly do you mean by citizens’ rights?

Not sure if I used the right words.  I would like to work right away, apply for housing and obtain healthcare.  I cannot find anything online regarding the amount of time I must be resident in Austria to regain access to healthcare after a long stay out of the country.

As an Austrian citizen you are always authorized to work in Austria and can begin working the moment you arrive from abroad.


I like to work right away, apply for housing and obtain healthcare

Since health insurance (Krankenversicherung) is mandatory when working, you will be registered (if not a member allready) once you start working and the coverage will start from the first day of work.
In how far assistance is given in looking for a place to stay may depend on the town you wish to live in, but in most cases you are expected to look for one yourself.


Beginn und Ende der Pflichtversicherung
(Österreichische Gesundheitskasse)
Beginn

Als Dienstnehmerin/Dienstnehmer oder Lehrling sind Sie mit Beginn Ihrer Tätigkeit versichert. Ihr Dienstgeber meldet Sie vor Arbeitsantritt bei der ÖGK an.
Als Pensionistin oder Pensionist sind Sie mit Beginn Ihrer Pension versichert.
Als arbeitslose Person sind Sie ab dem Bezug des Arbeitslosengeldes versichert.


Start and end of compulsory insurance
(Austrian Health Insurance Fund)
Start

As an employee or apprentice, you are insured from the start of your employment. Your employer registers you with the ÖGK before you start work.
As a pensioner, you are insured from the start of your pension.
As an unemployed person, you are insured from the time you start receiving unemployment benefit.



